# Compare 2 different months

Tags: javascript

I am displaying the single  month attendance based on from date and to date field selection by the user.

How to compare last year month to current year month?

for example

```
var from_date=1 dec 2016;
var to_date= 1 march 2017;
 if (form_date.getMonth()<to_date.getMonth())
 {
   alert('true');
 }
 else {
   alert('false');
 }
```

Actually it is true, but it is giving false .

Comment: Why don't you just compare the timestamps ?

Comment: `from_date !== form_date` and you can compare valid dates only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it isn't true. If you compare December (month = 12) with March (month = 3), then December is not less than March.

If you want to compare dates, then something like this can be use:

```
var from_date = new Date(2016, 11, 1),
  to_date = new Date(2017, 2, 1);

if (from_date < to_date) {
  :
} else {
  :
}
```

You have to be careful when creating dates - the month is zero-based, so December is 11 not 12.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert from_date and to_date to js objects
try the below code ..

```
var date1 = new Date(2016,11,1);
var date2 =  new Date(2017,2,1); // 1 Jan -> 30 Dec
if (date1.getMonth()<date2.getMonth())
{
  alert('true');
}
else {
  alert('false');
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Using the month alone will give the wrong results.